# GoogleApiClient connect always fails first time but gets successful second time

Tags: android, google-api-client

I have a google plus login set up for app through `GoogleApiClient`.

Whenever the app is installed first time and tries to make connection through `GoogleApiClient` it never gets successful and always end up at `onConnectionFailed` with `result` containing:

```
ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{4130e760: android.os.BinderProxy@4130e700}}
```

But when second time login its called it gets successful and `onConnected` hits. Why is that is it possible to make it successful over the first attempt?

Is there something wrong in my `Builder` parameters?

```
public void connectGoogleApi() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mainAppContext).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
        mConnectionResult = result;
        resolveSignInError();
    }

}
```

Comment: isnt it obvious by the error, the user needs to allow your app to authenticate

Comment: No dialog comes up and how it gets successful next time without user doing anytihng?

Answer (score 2):

As official docs says [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client#start_a_manually_managed_connection):

> If you are using GoogleApiClient to connect to APIs that require authentication, like Google Drive or Google Play Games, there's a good chance your first connection attempt will fail and your app will receive a call to onConnectionFailed() with the SIGN_IN_REQUIRED error because the user account was not specified.

Comment: Great to know. That helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, calling 'connect()' again, this time inside 'onConnected' method fixed it. Strange.

```
@Override
   public void onConnected(final Bundle arg0) {
   Logger.log("On connected");
   DevicePreferences.getGoogleApiClient().connect();
}
```